# Question about Arbitrage

Tags: bitcoin-core, arbitrage

So I just happen to know that arbitrage is possible yesterday and found a way to detect an arbitrage opportunity across all exchanges through all markets. But the thing that sucked is that exchanges disable the deposit and withdrawal whenever a coin is feasible for an arbitrage. My question is that, would it be possible to send coins to an exchange that disabled the deposit to that coin? I

Comment: You could send it, but they are under no obligation to process that deposit, and it might take you a while/battle with the customer support to eventually get them back

Answer (score 2):

You should never deposit your coin to an exchange when the deposit function is disabled, your transaction will either be delayed or just gone.